# Sort table (list of lists) according to specific ordered list (and other options)

Tags: python, sorting

I've done some research but could not find the way to order a table (list of lists) by a column following a specific order (i.e. given by a specific list).

I have a table made by a list of lists where each sublist represent a row of the table and each of its elements are the column values of that row.

My_table has 4 columns and I need to sort the table according to several options.
I am currently sorting it by the first column and then by the second column, as follows

```
My_table=sorted(My_table, key=lambda a: ( a[0], a[1]))
```

Now I need to sort My_table by the first column first and then by the third column, but the third column (which contains only integers) must be sorted according to a specific list where the integers have a specific order, say: custom_list=[3,0,1,2]. (Note: the integers of the list are all the possible values that can appear in that column, but not all of them necessarily appear).

How do I apply that sorting?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You're sorting by the first and third columns, but not the third column but a custom list instead ... Could you please clarify this?

Comment: Let me re-explain: the first column contains integers and is sorted "normally" like this:
`My_table=sorted(My_table, key=lambda a: ( a[0])`
but I want also to sort by the third column which also contains integers; but I want to sort the integers according to the order defined in a custom_list,  e.g. custom_list=[3,0,1,2].
I hope it is clearer now.
(Note: the integers of the list are all the possible values that can appear in the third column, but not all of them necessarily appear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe something like this?

```
order_of_3rd = [3,0,1,2]
My_table.sort(key=lambda a: (a[0], order_of_3rd.index(a[2])))
```

***Note**: if you are just assigning the sorted list back to the original list, you may as well use the inplace list sort*

Comment: Your dictionary has keys which are sequential integers starting from 0.  If this really is the case, a `list` is a better data structure.

Comment: @cmd: It worked!, thanks a lot!  
>>> pprint(table)  
[(0, 30.0, 2, 30.0, u' col_agriculture'),  
 (0, 153.0, 0, 153.0, u' col_agriculture'),  
 (0, 190.0, 1, 190.0, u' col_agriculture'),  
 (1, 74.0, 2, 74.0, u' col_manufacturing'),  
 (1, 66.0, 0, 66.0, u' col_manufacturing'),  
 (1, 845.0, 1, 845.0, u' col_manufacturing'),  
 (2, 10.0, 2, 10.0, u' col_services'),  
 (2, 33.0, 0, 33.0, u' col_services'),  
 (2, 29.0, 1, 29.0, u' col_services')]